# Calling JSON commands to armoryd

Tags: bitcoind, armory

I know with `bitcoind`, you can easily start the daemon and call some commands.

But with `armoryd`, I start it up with a wallet argument.

What are some examples of using the JSON-RPC to call a method for it?

For example, with `bitcoind` I can type in my shell:

```
bitcoind listaccounts
```

Is there a easy way to get my `armoryd` daemon to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

In your install directory, you should have armoryd.py.  Once you run

```
python armoryd.py
```

then you have a daemon.  Now you can run

```
python armoryd.py help
```

to get a list of commands like this (which can then be run with `python armoryd.py <command>`):

```
{
"backupwallet": {
    "Description": "Back up the current wallet to a file at a given location. The backup will occur only if the file does not exist yet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "backupFilePath - Path to the location where the backup will be saved."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary indicating whether or not the backup succeeded or failed, with the reason for failure given if applicable."
},
"clearaddressmetadata": {
    "Description": "Clear all armoryd-specific metadata for the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "None"
},
"createlockbox": {
    "Description": "Create an m-of-n lockbox associated with wallets loaded onto the armoryd server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "numM - The number of signatures required to spend lockbox funds.",
        "numN - The total number of signatures associated with a lockbox.",
        "args - The wallets or public keys associated with a lockbox, the total of which must match <numN> in number. The wallets are represented by their Base58 IDs. The keys must be uncompressed."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with information about the new lockbox."
},
"createustxformany": {
    "Description": "Create an unsigned transaction to be sent to multiple recipients from the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "args - An indefinite number of comma-separated sets of recipients and the number of Bitcoins to send to the recipients. The recipients can be an address, a P2SH script address, a lockbox (e.g., \"Lockbox[83jcAqz9]\" or \"Lockbox[Bare:83jcAqz9]\"), or a public key (compressed or uncompressed) string."
    ],
    "Return Value": "An ASCII-formatted unsigned transaction, similar to the one output by Armory for offline signing."
},
"createustxtoaddress": {
    "Description": "Create an unsigned transaction to be sent to one recipient from the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "recAddr - The recipient. This can be an address, a P2SH script address, a lockbox (e.g., \"Lockbox[83jcAqz9]\" or \"Lockbox[Bare:83jcAqz9]\"), or a public key (compressed or uncompressed) string.",
        "amount - The number of Bitcoins to send to the recipient."
    ],
    "Return Value": "An ASCII-formatted unsigned transaction, similar to the one output by Armory for offline signing."
},
"decoderawtransaction": {
    "Description": "Decode a raw transaction hex string.",
    "Parameters": [
        "hexString - A string representing, in hex form, a raw transaction."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary containing the decoded transaction's information."
},
"dumpprivkey": {
    "Description": "Dump the private key for a given Base58 address associated with the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "addr58 - A Base58 public address associated with the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "The 32 byte binary private key."
},
"encryptwallet": {
    "Description": "Encrypt a wallet with a given passphrase.",
    "Parameters": [
        "passphrase - The wallet's new passphrase."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating that the encryption was successful."
},
"getactivelockbox": {
    "Description": "Get the lockbox ID of the currently active lockbox.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "The Base58 ID for the currently active lockbox."
},
"getactivewallet": {
    "Description": "Get the wallet ID of the currently active wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "The Base58 ID for the currently active wallet."
},
"getaddrbalance": {
    "Description": "Get the balance of a Base58 address associated with the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "inB58 - The Base58 address associated with the current wallet.",
        "baltype - (Default=spendable) A string indicating the balance type to retrieve from the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "The current wallet balance (BTC), or -1 if an error occurred."
},
"getaddressmetadata": {
    "Description": "Get all armoryd-specific metadata for the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with all metadata sent to armoryd."
},
"getarmorydinfo": {
    "Description": "Get information on the version of armoryd running on the server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary listing version of armoryd running on the server."
},
"getbalance": {
    "Description": "Get the balance of the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "baltype - (Default=spendable) A string indicating the balance type to retrieve from the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "The current wallet balance (BTC), or -1 if an error occurred."
},
"getblock": {
    "Description": "Get the block associated with a given block hash.",
    "Parameters": [
        "blkhash - A hex string representing the block to obtain."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary listing information on the desired block, or empty if the block wasn't found."
},
"gethextxtobroadcast": {
    "Description": "Get a signed Tx from a file and get the raw hex data to broadcast.",
    "Parameters": [
        "txASCIIFile - The path to a file with an signed transacion."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A hex string of the raw transaction data to be transmitted."
},
"getledger": {
    "Error": "The function description is malformed."
},
"getledgersimple": {
    "Description": "Get a simple version of a wallet or lockbox ledger.",
    "Parameters": [
        "inB58ID - The Base58 ID of the wallet or lockbox from which to obtain the ledger. The wallet or lockbox must already be loaded.",
        "tx_count - (Default=10) The number of entries to get.",
        "from_tx - (Default=0) The first entry to get."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with a wallet ledger of type \"simple\"."
},
"getlockboxinfo": {
    "Description": "Get information on the lockbox associated with a lockbox ID string or, if it exists, the currently active armoryd lockbox.",
    "Parameters": [
        "inLBID - (Default=None) If used, armoryd will get information on the lockbox with the provided Base58 ID instead of the currently active armoryd lockbox.",
        "outForm - (Default=JSON) If used, armoryd will return the lockbox in a particular format. Choices are \"JSON\", \"Hex\", and \"Base64\"."
    ],
    "Return Value": "If the lockbox is found, a dictionary with information on the lockbox will be returned."
},
"getnewaddress": {
    "Description": "Get a new Base58 address from the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "The wallet's next unused public address in Base58 form."
},
"getrawtransaction": {
    "Description": "Get the raw transaction string for a given transaction hash.",
    "Parameters": [
        "txHash - A string representing the hex value of a transaction ID.",
        "verbose - (Default=0) Integer indicating whether or not the result should be more verbose.",
        "endianness - (Default=BIGENDIAN) Indicates the endianness of the ID."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with the decoded raw transaction and relevant information."
},
"getreceivedbyaddress": {
    "Description": "Get the number of coins received by a Base58 address associated with the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "address - The Base58 address associated with the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "The balance received from the incoming address (BTC)."
},
"gettransaction": {
    "Description": "Get the transaction associated with a given transaction hash.",
    "Parameters": [
        "txHash - A hex string representing the block to obtain."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary listing information on the desired transaction, or empty if the transaction wasn't found."
},
"gettxout": {
    "Description": "Get the TxOut entries for a given transaction hash.",
    "Parameters": [
        "txHash - A string representing the hex value of a transaction ID.",
        "n - The TxOut index to obtain.",
        "binary - (Default=0) Indicates whether or not the resultant binary script should be in binary form or converted to a hex string."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with the Bitcoin amount for the TxOut and the TxOut script in hex string form (default) or binary form."
},
"getwalletinfo": {
    "Description": "Get information on the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "inWltID - (Default=None) If used, armoryd will get info for the wallet for the provided Base58 wallet ID instead of the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with information on the current wallet."
},
"help": {
    "Description": "Get a directionary with all functions the armoryd server can run.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with all functions available on the armoryd server, along with the function parameters and function return value."
},
"importprivkey": {
    "Description": "Import a private key into the current wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "privKey - A private key in any format supported by Armory, including Base58 private keys supported by bitcoind (uncompressed public key support only)."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string of the private key's accompanying hexadecimal public key."
},
"listaddrunspent": {
    "Description": "Get a list of unspent transactions for the currently loaded wallet that are associated with a given, comma-separated list of Base58 addresses from the wallet. By default, zero-conf UTXOs are included.",
    "Parameters": [
        "inB58 - The Base58 address to check against the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary containing all UTXOs for the currently loaded wallet associated with the given Base58 address, along with information about each UTXO."
},
"listloadedlockboxes": {
    "Description": "List all lockboxes loaded onto the armoryd server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with the Base58 values of all lockboxes loaded in armoryd."
},
"listloadedwallets": {
    "Description": "List all wallets loaded onto the armoryd server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with the Base58 values of all wallets loaded in armoryd."
},
"listtransactions": {
    "Description": "List the transactions associated with the currently loaded wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "tx_count - (Default=10) The number of entries to get.",
        "from_tx - (Default=0) The first entry to get."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with information on the retrieved transactions."
},
"listunspent": {
    "Description": "Get a list of unspent transactions for the currently loaded wallet. By default, zero-conf UTXOs are included.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary listing information about each UTXO in the currently loaded wallet. The dictionary is similar to the one returned by the bitcoind call of the same name."
},
"receivedfromaddress": {
    "Description": "Return the number of coins received from a particular sender.",
    "Parameters": [
        "sender - Base58 address of the sender to the current wallet."
    ],
    "Return Value": "Number of Bitcoins sent by the sender to the current wallet."
},
"receivedfromsigner": {
    "Description": "Verify that a message (RFC 2440: clearsign or Base64) has been signed by a Bitcoin address and get the amount of coins sent to the current wallet by the message's signer.",
    "Parameters": [
        "sigBlock - Message with the RFC 2440 message to be verified. The message must be enclosed in quotation marks."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with verified message and the amount of money sent to the current wallet by the signer."
},
"relockwallet": {
    "Description": "Re-lock a wallet.",
    "Parameters": [
        "None"
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating whether or not the wallet is locked."
},
"sendlockbox": {
    "Description": "E-mail ASCII-encoded lockboxes to recipients.",
    "Parameters": [
        "lbIDs - A colon-delineated list of Base58 IDs of lockboxes to send to an email recipient.",
        "sender - The email address of the sender.",
        "server - The SMTP email server.",
        "pwd - The email account password.",
        "recips - The recipient or, if the string is delineated by a colon, a list of recipients.",
        "msgSubj - (Default=Armory Lockbox) The email subject."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating whether or not the attempt to send was successful."
},
"setactivelockbox": {
    "Description": "Set the currently active lockbox to one already loaded on the armoryd server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "newIDB58 - The Base58 ID of the lockbox to be made active."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating whether or not the lockbox was set as desired."
},
"setactivewallet": {
    "Description": "Set the currently active wallet to one already loaded on the armoryd server.",
    "Parameters": [
        "newIDB58 - The Base58 ID of the wallet to be made active."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating whether or not the wallet was set as desired."
},
"setaddressmetadata": {
    "Description": "Set armoryd-specific metadata associated with Base58 addresses.",
    "Parameters": [
        "newAddressMetaData - A dictionary containing arbitrary metadata to attach to Base58 addresses listed with the metadata."
    ],
    "Return Value": "None"
},
"signasciitransaction": {
    "Description": "Sign an unsigned transaction and get the signed ASCII data.",
    "Parameters": [
        "unsignedTxASCII - An ASCII-formatted unsigned transaction, like the one used by Armory for offline transactions.",
        "wltPasswd - (Default=None) If needed, the current wallet's password."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary containing a string with the ASCII-formatted signed transaction or, if the signing failed, a string indicating failure."
},
"unlockwallet": {
    "Description": "Unlock a wallet with a given passphrase and unlock time length.",
    "Parameters": [
        "passphrase - The wallet's current passphrase.",
        "timeout - (Default=10) The time, in seconds, that the wallet will be unlocked."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A string indicating if the wallet was unlocked or if it was already unlocked."
},
"verifysignature": {
    "Description": "Take a message (RFC 2440: clearsign or Base64) signed by a Bitcoin address and verify the message.",
    "Parameters": [
        "sigBlock - Message with the RFC 2440 message to be verified. The message must be enclosed in quotation marks."
    ],
    "Return Value": "A dictionary with verified message and the Base58 address of the signer."
},
"watchwallet": {
    "Description": "Send an e-mail notification when the current wallet spends money.",
    "Parameters": [
        "send_from - The email address of the sender.",
        "smtpServer - (Default=None) The SMTP email server.",
        "password - (Default=None) The email account password.",
        "send_to - (Default=None) The recipient or, if the string is delineated by a colon, a list of recipients.",
        "subject - (Default=None) The email subject.",
        "watchCmd - (Default=add) A string indicating if emails from the sender should be sent or, if set to \"remove\", emails from the sender that are currently being sent should be stopped."
    ],
    "Return Value": "None"
}
}
```

Source: [armoryd.README](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/armoryd.README) in the install folder

Comment: Good answer! It looks like the closest analogue to what the asker is looking for is `listloadedwallets`.